# getting error in DropBox integration to the iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, dropbox-api, app-id

I am trying to integrate the DropBox to my iPhone app. But I get error like

```
[ERROR] DropboxSDK: unable to link; app isn't registered for correct URL scheme (db-xpt9oxj57x9ftci)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Most of the time that problem is caused by a misconfigured Info.plist file. Can you make sure you've followed the documentation/index.html about changing Info.plist file? In info plist set db-key in urltype (urlschema). That should do the trick.

Comment: I forgot to write 'db' in plist. Thank you

Comment: I think you just gave away your dropbox api key for everyone to use. I want to edit this and take it out for you but I'm afraid that would be abusing my `editor` privileges.

Answer (score 4):

I googled and the Dropbox sdk has the line specifically to add the the app key in your app plist file

> Your app key is also needed in DBRoulette-Info.plist file so the app
>   can register for the correct url scheme. To do this, find the file
>   under the Resources group in the left pane, right-click it and select
>   Open As → Source Code. Replace the text APP_KEY with your app's key

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/setup#ios

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution.

I am working with Xamarin in Windows Visual Studio 2015, and as presented in other queries online, there is no "URL scheme" option available.  So the solution is to modify info.plist by hand.  Your dropbox specific plist scheme should look like this:

```html
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>dbapi-2</string>
    <string>dbapi-8-emm</string>
  </array>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
      <array>
        <string>db-APP_KEY</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </array>
```

A great helper for me to get this information was the "info.plist" for [this](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/ios).  This "info" modification should work for any xamarin project.

Answer (score 0):

If you fix any typos or forget the "db" and are still having problems, clean & rebuild may help.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL scheme should be `db-<Your App key>`. Example `db-a7ghdtthegj6z1g`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue just now and was done in by a space before the db- prefix. Hard to see in the plist editor, but very obvious when I looked at the XML.